# install package with bower components is not correctly

Tags: bower

I have this code in my webstorm IDE in the Terminal dialog:

```
bower install angular-ui-router
```

When I look now in my app/bower_components folder I can see the new created folder with angular-ui-router package.

But what I would have expected is also an entry in the bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "angular-route": "1.2.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
  }
}
```

I does not see the angular-ui-router anywhere!

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--save` flag to get it in your bower.json:

```
bower install --save angular-ui-router
```

Comment: Why is this not be default? What is the reason?